# How to Shuffle Product Collection in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, category, product-collection, product-sorting, random

I am getting products collection form multiple categories. I want to shuffle products everytime when function getProductCollection() is called.
My function is:

```
public function getProductCollection($categories)
{
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => $categories]);
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
    $collection->setPageSize(5);
    return $collection;
}
```

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => $categories]);
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
$collection->setPageSize(5);
$collection ->getSelect()->orderRand();
//or use this line $collection->getSelect()->order('RAND()');
return $collection;
```

Comment: Happy to help :) Happy Coding !!

Comment: Does this code shows random product on every page refresh?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => $categories]);
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
    $collection->setPageSize(5);
    $collection ->getSelect()->orderRand();
    return $collection;
```